# Изменение стиля в зависимости от содержания в URL

Tags: javascript

Необходимо применить к классу .template-text свойство display: none в зависимости от содержания url. 
Есть url - http://site.ru/pricelist/SLP/WSK127/, как сделать что бы, при наличии в урле 'pricelist' добавить к данному классу display:none

```
if (location.href == 'pricelist') {
    var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('template-text');
    for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)elems[i].style.display='none';
}
else{
    false;
}
```

Вот это не работает, в консоли никаких ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно искать подстроку в строке с помощью [indexOf](https://javascript.ru/string/indexof).

```js
let url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf('pricelist') !== -1) {
    let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('template-text');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
else {
    false;
}
```